# change the color of the footer in the first page of the fancy

Tags: header-footer, color, memoir, fancyhdr

I am using this to change the color of the headers and footer of the chapter pages in the fancy page style, which I got from another post.

```
     \usepackage{etoolbox}

     \makeatletter
     \patchcmd{\@fancyhead}{\rlap}{\color{ared}\rlap}{}{} 
     \patchcmd{\headrule}{\hrule}{\color{ared}\hrule}{}{}
     \patchcmd{\@fancyfoot}{\rlap}{\color{ared}\rlap}{}{}
     \patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule}{\color{ared}\hrule}{}{}
     \makeatother
```

however, the in the first page of every chapter, the page number remains in black. I have tried modifying the `\fancypagestyle{plain}` but so far not results.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to successfully change the first chapter page footer color?

I am using the [`memoir` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir).

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) you should not really be using `fancyhdr` with `memoir`, it has its own heavily integrated system for handling headers. (3) On this site we prefer full minimal examples can that be copied and tested without having to add anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunaly there is no MWE in the question. With `memoir` you should use the  header and footer commands of this class:

```
 \documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{ared}{red}

\pagestyle{ruled}
\makeevenhead{ruled}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}
\makeoddhead{ruled}{\rightmark}{}{\leftmark}
\makeevenfoot{ruled}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{ruled}{}{\thepage}{}

\makeheadfootruleprefix{ruled}{\color{ared}}{\color{ared}}
\makeheadfootstrut{ruled}{\strut\color{ared}}{\strut\color{ared}}
\makeheadfootstrut{plain}{\strut\color{ared}}{\strut\color{ared}}
\uppercaseheads

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With a **standard class** you can use `fancyhdr` but then you have to define `plain` as a fancy page style too:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{ared}{red}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@fancyhead}{\rlap}{\color{ared}\rlap}{}{} 
\patchcmd{\headrule}{\hrule}{\color{ared}\hrule}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@fancyfoot}{\rlap}{\color{ared}\rlap}{}{}
\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule}{\color{ared}\hrule}{}{}
\makeatother

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or you could use package `scrlayer-scrpage`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{ared}{red}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline,markcase=upper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\color{ared}}
\ohead{\leftmark}
\ihead{\rightmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}


\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP is using [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir).

Comment: @Werner There is also a suggestion for `memoir`(without `fancyhdr`) in my answer including a colored headsepline.

Comment: Ahhh, I see now. Missed that.